# Paralax Materialize

Tags: html, materialize

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parallax').parallax();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">



<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper container">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Vowel</a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="collapsible.html">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Subscribe</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax">
    <img src="images/london.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row container">
    <h2>Title text</h2>
  
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row container">
    <h2>Title text</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="images/nyc.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row container">
    <h2>Title text</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row container">
    <h2>Title text</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="parallax-container">
    <div class="parallax"><img src="images/nyc.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col l6 s12">
    <h5 class="white-text">Footer Content</h5>
    <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">You can use rows and 
    columns here to organize your footer content.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
    <h5 class="white-text">Links</h5><ul>
    <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright">
    <div class="container">
      © 2014 Copyright Text
      <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </footer>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

I know that this question was here before but I couldn't solve my problem at all. I don't know why my paralax doesn't work. I don't have any CSS for that nor other scripts. Any thoughts what might be my problem? I downloaded jquery as well and put to the folder where I have my website files, it didn't work. I tried different versions, and I pasted one script below/above the other to see if can work - it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the parallax function calling is written below the  library files linked

```
<link href="css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"rel="stylesheet">


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.parallax').parallax();
});
</script>
```